# Does MySQL with Entity Framework 6 supported in .Net Core 3.1 application for 2 separated projects?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, .net-core

i have two separated projects -> DAL that targets .Net Framework 4.7.2 and it's a data access layer that uses MySQL Database with Entity Framework 6  (Database first approach)
REST API that targets .Net Core 3.1
when trying to call any SP or DBSet instance of the Context class , it crashes for MySQL Provider registration ( even though MySQL and Entity Framework are referenced in the project)
Is there something missing or MySQL is not supported for .Net Core 3.1 ?

[attached is screenshot of the App.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CIYr.png)

Comment: Support for databases is through providers, not EF itself. Which provider did you use? .NET Core has no `app.config` and even in .NET Old, it's not used to add references to NuGet packages or reference libraries. Both in .NET Old and .NET Core EF providers are added as NuGet packages.

Comment: _"it crashes for MySQL Provider registration"_ - that's not a proper problem description. Read [ask], research the actual error and show what you have tried.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm using MySql.Data.MySqlClient 
the App.config is for .Net Project (DAL)

Comment: @CodeCaster : this is the exception i get "System.ArgumentException: 'The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded"

Comment: @Sally that's the namespace, not the actual provider's name. Multiple providers may use the same namespace for compatibility purposes. And even the assembly name may have nothing to do with the actual name. Oracle's provider for example is called `Connector/NET`. You **can't** add references in `app.config`. You need to either use `Add Reference` from the project menu or add a NuGet file.

Comment: The error you get says you haven't installed any provider. ADO.NET providers are *not* bundled with the runtime (except for SQL Server, but even that is changing now). Did you install Oracle's Connector/Net? Did you buy DevArt's driver? Install the Pomelo open-source provider from NuGet?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : I installed the MySQL Connector/Net version 8.0.21 
Regarding Pomelo; it is targeting EF Core and i'm using EF 6 .
Also to mention that i tried calling CRUD operation from Web API that targets .Net Framework 4.7.2 and it worked fine but when calling it from .Net Core Web API it crashes for the mentioned error above